# How can I sort these words to make this sentence in Python?

Tags: python

I have to sort these words in to a sentence.
This is my list, with the numbers:

```
sms=['Szentírás ', 'bölcs ', 'a ', 'már ', 'szükséges ', 'mondhat ', 'biztosak ', 'a ', 
     'feladata, ', 'Mivel ', 'ellent ', 'a ', 'érzéki ', 'azokkal ', 'következtetésekkel, ',
     'a ', 'vagyunk ', 'a ', 'tapasztalataink ', 'szöveg ', 'azon ', 'igazság ', 'sose ',
     'ami ', 'hogy ', 'melyekben ', 'kísérletek ', 'megtalálják ', 'által.', 'két ', 'fizikai ',
     'egymásnak, ', 'egyezik ', 'és ', 'értelmezőinek ', 'értelmezését, ']
sorrend=[8,9,15,26,33,4,27,11,12,0,5,32,29,21,24,22,28,7,30,16,17,2,3,19,13,25,34,14,35,1,23,6,20,31,10,18]
```

and I have to get this sentence:

```
Mivel  két  igazság  sose  mondhat  ellent  egymásnak,  a  Szentírás  bölcs  értelmezőinek  a  feladata,  hogy  megtalálják  a  szöveg  azon  értelmezését,  ami  egyezik  azokkal  a  fizikai  következtetésekkel,  melyekben  már  biztosak  vagyunk  érzéki  tapasztalataink  és  a  szükséges  kísérletek  által.
```

How can I sort it like that?
Thanks.

Comment: the number index you provide does not match the desired output.

Comment: On what basis do you want these words sorted? These indices does not correspond to the desired output.

Comment: Yes, but it matches with the mixed words given, and i have to connect, and then sort them somehow.

Comment: This is the task: You received an SMS, but unfortunately, because of a network error, the words got mixed. We read that in our phone: ...(sms)...
The provider sent us the right order (sorrend).
In the original sentence, the 8th index was the 9th word...

Comment: sure the 8th index is the 9th word but the 9th word is `feladata` but your expected output shows `Mivel`, do you see the discrepancy? Otherwise the answer to this problem is straightforward one-liner

Comment: Okay, then for short..
This is my list:
sms=['love', 'I', 'much', 'so', 'you']
sorrend=[2,1,5,4,3]
I have to get the sentence : I love you so much.
How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
dict(sorted(zip(sorrend,sms))).values()
```

For your shortened example:

```
>>> sms=['love', 'I', 'much', 'so', 'you']
>>> sorrend=[2,1,5,4,3]
>>> ' '.join(dict(sorted(zip(sorrend,sms))).values())
'I love you so much'
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've solved this riddle:

```
words = {}
for i in range(len(sorrend)):
    words[sorrend[i]] = sms[i]

for i in range(len(sorrend)):
    print(words[i], end=' ')
```

Output:

```
Mivel  két  igazság  sose  mondhat  ellent  egymásnak,  a  Szentírás  bölcs  értelmezőinek  a  feladata,  hogy  megtalálják  a  szöveg  azon  értelmezését,  ami  egyezik  azokkal  a  fizikai  következtetésekkel,  melyekben  már  biztosak  vagyunk  érzéki  tapasztalataink  és  a  szükséges  kísérletek  által.
```

Comment: Key to solve this problem was to move ith word in `sms` to the position that corresponds to the ith number in `sorrend`. Like `'Szentírás '` has to be at 8th index in the output.